# How can I pass Destruction magic test in College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What are the spells I need to know?

I forgot which one she said to do, I've tried flames and firebolt, there's something that starts with an A but I can't remember what it's called, she isn't selling anything like it and I wouldn't know where to find it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:First_Lessons)

> If you agree, [Faralda] will randomly select one spell from any one of the five schools of magic for you to cast. This may be:
>
> - Casting a Firebolt at the eye-shaped seal next to her.
> - Conjuring a Flame Atronach on the seal.
> - Casting Fear at the seal.
> - Casting Healing Hands on her.
> - Casting Magelight at the seal.
>
> If you do not have the spell she asks of you, she will offer to teach it to you for 30 gold. This is an easy and cheap way to learn any one of the above spells.
>
> You must cast the spell at the circular impression in the floor behind her. Casting the spell in any other location will not progress the quest. However, if she asks you to conjure a Flame Atronach, and you already have a Flame Thrall summoned, simply exiting the conversation and speaking to her again will successfully progress the dialogue.

so doing all those things should eventually get you in if you've forgotten

> there's something that starts with an A but I can't remember what it's called

this probably is the **Flame Atronach** so i would start with that. also keep in mind that these aren't all destruction spells

- Firebolt = Destruction
- Flame Atronach = Conjuration
- Fear =  Illusion
- Healing Hands = Restoration
- Magelight = Alteration

otherwise there's 2 other ways to get passed her without magic

> Alternatively, you can attempt to persuade her and avoid this test. In order to persuade her, you will need a Speech skill of 100 (70 with the Persuasion perk) or an Amulet of Articulation, available only by completing the Thieves Guild questline and becoming Guildmaster. If you are on the quest Elder Knowledge you can also mention that you are Dragonborn. She will then ask to see a shout. Either of these will get you in without needing to cast a spell.

The Method using the shout would be the easiest since you would have gotten Unrelenting Force as apart of the questline

Comment: I have Firebolt but using it doesn't do anything and she doesn't have Flame Atronach for sale, and no matter what I say to her she never specifies what spell to use or offers to sell it to me. When I ask about the test she just says "are you ready" and my only option is to say "nevermind"

Comment: I'm pretty sure I bought firebolt from her but I've used it on the seal over and over again and nothing happens

Comment: @voltaire check my edit to see if you're standing in the right place

Comment: @voltaire Looks like you just need to go down the list buying spells until one of them works

Comment: thank you I'm gonna try all of these things. New to the whole elder scrolls series lol I'm learning as I go

Comment: She seems kinda buggy - she asked me to cast flame atronach and said if I didn't know it, she would teach it to me for 30g, but there's no option to get her to do so, just a single option that restarts her dialogue. I had to go learn the spell from a tome I picked up elsewhere (not tested if it works yet).